# Webpack 4 - Exposing variable to global context

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, ecmascript-6, bundler

I'm making a lib wrote in ES6 and will transpile it with Babel to the past version to avoid EcmaScript incompatibility.

```
class MyLib {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  sayHello() {
    return `Hello ${this.name}`;
  }
}

// Would this work / is this the right way?
// window.MyLib = MyLib

module.exports = MyLib;
```

This lib *must* be in the global scope, for the user does not need to import it from anywhere, or even has a simple HTML + CSS structure without the overhead of having a bundler like webpack configured.

What's the "right way" to make this lib available on the global scope?

A `window.MyLib = MyLib` before a `module.exports` would work or is the right way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I thus configure my "webpack.config.js" file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./index.js",
        output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/"),
        filename: "out_file_name.js",
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        globalObject: 'this',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        library: 'libraryName'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        cacheDirectory: true,
                        presets: ["babel-preset-env"]
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

In the file "index.js":

```
function createLibraryName() {
    return {
        func1: () => {},
        func2: () => {},
        //...
    };
}

export default createLibraryName();
```

This way I can access the library like this:

```
libraryName.func1();
libraryName.func2();
```